# CSS icon difficult to click

Tags: css

I have come up with my own plus icon since font-awesome analogue seemed to thick for me. But I have one issue: It is very difficult to click on the icon. The user has to put the cursor exactly on the minus sign in order to click the icon or see the tooltip.

```css
.plus {
  position: relative;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.plus:before,
.plus:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 15px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.plus:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<i id='new_contact' class="plus" title='Create contact' data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-head="New sms">
   </i>
```

Comment: I think your code is incomplete, isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, problems like these are usually solved by adding a small padding around the icon.

Comment: make it inline-block - you have no height or width at the moment which is why it isn't clickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, I have changed your `.plus` to have a `display: block;` a `background: blue;` and a `padding: 3px;` to show you how it is working.

When changing the position of the icon itself, you may need to edit your `.plus:before` class to align with the padding.

I hope this helped ! http://jsfiddle.net/6rekek66/1/

```css
.plus {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  padding: 3px;
}

.plus:before,
.plus:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 15px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.plus:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<i id='new_contact' class="plus" title='Create contact' data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-head="New sms">
   </i>
```

Comment: To quote @pete, make it inline-block as well to make sure it has height and width.

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan Working on it.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you've changed to achieve this?

Comment: In your second block of CSS code, i chaged you left: 7px; to left: 9px; !

Answer (score 0):

Basically adding `display: block` will solve this. Here I have also added a temporary pink background to make the clickable zone clearer, and tweaked a couple more values.

```css
.plus {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: pink;
}

.plus:before,
.plus:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 15px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.plus:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><i id='new_contact' class="plus" title='Create contact' data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-head="New sms">
</i></a>
```